# Is this a mistake in my multi-variable calculus practice sheets?

Tags: calculus, multivariable-calculus, proof-verification

The following is a problem in one of my teacher's practice sheets:

> Let $f(x,y)=\root{3} \of {xy}$. Show $f_x(0,0)$ and $f_y({0,0})$ exist by giving values for them.

Now, it's been a long day, but I do not believe I am mistaken in saying these values do not exist. If a quick visualization of the graph of $y=\root3 \of {ax}$ for constant $a$ was not proof enough, I give the following argument for the non-existence of a real value for the partial derivatives at $(0,0)$ with respect to $x$ and $y$ :

Let $y=0$. Then $f_x(0,0) = \lim_{a \to 0}f_x(a,0)  = \lim_{a \to 0}\frac{0}{3 \root{3} \of {a^2}} = 0.$

Let $y=x^2$. Then $f_x(0,0) = \lim_{a \to 0}f_x(a,a^2) = \lim_{a \to 0}\frac{\root{3} \of a^2}{3 \root{3} \of a^2} = \frac{1}{3}$.

Contradiction, $f_x(0,0)$ does not exist. Similarly, $f_y(0,0)$ does not exist.

This is a bit of overkill, but my only reason for going through all this trouble is because I am not sure if this question is flawed or because my methods are. Am I missing something? Or is the question's presumption incorrect?

Comment: To be explicit: You must use the *definition* of the partial derivative at the origin. You approach along the axes, where the function is identically $0$. Forget formulas.

Comment: Also, to your visualization point: what does the graph of $y = \sqrt[3]{ax}$ look like when $a=0$?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I put a problem like this on a quiz today and the majority of my students fell into the same trap. It's **not true** in general that
$$
    \color{red}{f_x(0,0) = \lim_{a \to 0} f_x(a,0)}
$$
etc. Only in certain cases (like $f$ when is $C^1$; that is, has continuous partial derivatives) can you say this.

If you use the definition,
\begin{align*}
    f_x(0,0) = \lim_{a \to 0} \frac{f(a,0) - f(0,0)}{a} = \lim_{a\to 0} \frac{0}{a} = 0
\end{align*}
And likewise for $f_y(0,0)$.

What you have shown is that $\lim_{(x,y) \to (0,0)} f_x(x,y)$ does not exist, so $f$ is not $C^1$ at $(0,0)$.